# linker error when add static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, linker-errors

I have a static library(libMoboSDK.a file) and a folder(.h files). Then try to add to my project. When I add I got error with library search paths, not sure for the root cause. But when many search, I tried to delete **Library search paths** as advice on stackoverflow. But after that I got the error:

`ld: library not found for -lMoboSDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

```
Ld /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboLibfile.app/TestMoboLibfile normal i386
cd /Users/nle/Documents/Projects/TestMoboLibfile
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/nle/Documents/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Intermediates/TestMoboLibfile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboLibfile.build/Objects-normal/i386/TestMoboLibfile.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework FacebookSDK -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework CoreTelephony -weak_framework StoreKit -weak_framework XCTest -lMoboSDK -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lMoboSDK -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Intermediates/TestMoboLibfile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboLibfile.build/Objects-normal/i386/TestMoboLibfile_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboLibfile.app/TestMoboLibfile
```

I had tried many research. But also cannot solve the prolem.Here is my setting:
[image: project setting]

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** After many tried, I got the error which have the same describe with many errors on stackoverflow. But also cannot find a solution can resolve my problem. Here is the new describe of error:

```
   ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/nle/Documents/Projects/TestMoboLibfile/libMoboSDK.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/nle/Documents/Projects/TestMoboLibfile/libMoboSDK.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MoboSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboLibfile.app/TestMoboLibfile normal i386
cd /Users/nle/Documents/Projects/TestMoboLibfile
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/nle/Documents/Projects/TestMoboLibfile -L/Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboSDK-Client-dszxjhzvvskuqjfzvsxotqrpwfdr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/nle/Documents/Projects/TestMoboLibfile -F/Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/nle/Documents/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Intermediates/TestMoboLibfile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboLibfile.build/Objects-normal/i386/TestMoboLibfile.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -lMoboSDK -framework FacebookSDK -weak_framework AdSupport -framework CoreTelephony -framework StoreKit -weak_framework XCTest -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Intermediates/TestMoboLibfile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboLibfile.build/Objects-normal/i386/TestMoboLibfile_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboLibfile-dledhcaafocrregpqyxrmoqdaokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboLibfile.app/TestMoboLibfile
```

Comment: If it's the third party library then please check the readme.txt of it, there must be some line stating to set some flag for the linker.P.S: Follow the readme.txt

Comment: Please show the whole configuration of your library search path, and the directory in path in which you put your library.

Comment: No, it's my static library. I create a static library then add it to another project to use the functions into the library.

Comment: @CarmeloS I also tried add : $(SRCROOT)/ into library search path. but not solved the problem.

Comment: Yes; you should be configuring the `Library Search Path`, not the `Framework Search Path`.  If the library code is in a sibling folder then it would be something like `$(SRCROOT)/../LibName/lib` or somesuch.

Comment: @trojanfoe: here is the values into my **Library Search Paths** :`$(SRCROOT)/
$(USER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboSDK-Client-dszxjhzvvskuqjfzvsxotqrpwfdr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
$(PROJECT_DIR)`

Comment: Well that doesn't mean much to me (I've never used `$(USER_LIBRARY_DIR)` when configuring anything in Xcode).  Bottom line: find out what that actually expands to, use Finder/Command prompt to see what's there.  Rectify any differences.

Comment: I also check into folder with path:`$(USER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboSDK-Client-dszxjhzvvskuqjfzvsxotqrpwfdr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos` and it have .a file

Comment: after tried many change.still not work.

Comment: @trojanfoe: here source code from [bitbucket][1] [1]: https://bitbucket.org/nhatle/testusestaticlibrary/downloads

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance!

Comment: it seems to me that you tried to use your library that built for ios device only on simulator. try building your library again for i386 and add it to your project then you can use it on simulator.

Comment: @3329:How to build for i386? can you explain in detail?

Comment: **The easiest ways** is to make the lib project as a subproject of your new project. That way, Xcode will build both your project and dependent libs for the same architecture automatically. Or **if you can't do that**, you only have to go to your lib project and select target to an iOS simulator then build it. _The lib you get this way can use on simulator only_. So, simulator and device have to use separate libs unless you combine them together. Just search for **"fat static library"**, there are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I don't want to make lib project as a subproject.So I will research for **fat static library** as your recommend.